# Sound in Ubuntu Studio 23.10

Tags: sound, soundcard

I need the sound to work on my computer and I can't, I have Ubuntu Studio 23.10 installed and an Asus Xonar SE sound card, but I can't get the mic to work, it has another sound card on the motherboard, it's a Realtek that doesn't work either very well, the fact is that I have to give some talks by teleconference and I can't give them. Could someone help me, I use an automatic translator because I don't speak English, I'm from Spain.